# Datatable - Cannot read property 'sSortAscending' of undefined

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I´m trying to reload data of a datatable. To do that i clean table then add rows dynamically.

JS

```
 if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tbl_mostrar_alarmas')) {
        $('#tbl_mostrar_alarmas').DataTable().clear().rows.add(tablaModalData).columns.adjust().draw(); //I SUPPOSE THAT ERROR HERE 
    }

 $('#tbl_mostrar_alarmas').DataTable({
        'responsive': true,
        'bRetrieve': true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        'pageLength': 5,
        "data": tablaModalData,
        "order": [
            0, 'desc'
        ],
        "columns": [{
                "data": "fecha",
                "defaultContent": "-",
            },
            {
                "data": "usuario",
                "defaultContent": "-"
            },
            {
                "data": "suceso",
                "defaultContent": "-",
            }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 0,
            render: function(data) {
                return moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
            }
        }]

    })
}
```

HTML

```
<table id="tbl_mostrar_alarmas" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>DATA 1</th>
         <th>DATA 2</th>
         <th>DATA 3</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

Return

> jquery.dataTables.min.js:68 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'sSortAscending' of undefined

So, anybody knows what´s wrong?

Comment: Are you using a legacy version of datatables? The newer version uses `$('#tbl_mostrar_alarmas').DataTable` with a capital `D`. Please correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way rather :

```
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#achats_table")) {
    $('#tbl_mostrar_alarmas').DataTable().clear();
    $('#tbl_mostrar_alarmas').DataTable().destroy();
    $('#tbl_mostrar_alarmas').empty();
}
```

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre that means that it's trying to recreate the table before the destroy is finished. Try to initialize the datatabse using a captial D as I mentioned. Either that or replace my first two lines by `$("#tbl_mostrar_alarmas").dataTable().fnDestroy();`

Comment: I change datatable to Datatable (i update question too) and same error.

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre try recreating the problem then in a snippet. As the code I gave you IS the correct way to reinitialize datatables. If the error persists then the problem is coming from elsewhere and without further details I can't guess unfortunately.

Comment: I found solution and updated post with that. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre happy to have tried ;) Post your solution in a separate answer, explain what was wrong, and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I found solution. The error appear when i try to load datatable configuration multiple times. To avoid this i need to check if configuration was loaded (or not) and load it only once.

```
  if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tbl_mostrar_alarmas')) {
        $('#tbl_mostrar_alarmas').DataTable().clear().rows.add(tablaModalData).columns.adjust().draw();
    } else {
        table();
    }

    var table = $('#tbl_mostrar_alarmas').DataTable({
                'responsive': true,
                'bRetrieve': true,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                'pageLength': 5,
                "data": tablaModalData,
                "order": [
                    0, 'desc'
                ],
                "columns": [{
                        "data": "fecha",
                        "defaultContent": "-",
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "usuario",
                        "defaultContent": "-"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "suceso",
                        "defaultContent": "-",
                    }
                ],
                "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets": 0,
                    render: function(data) {
                        return moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
                    }
                }]
            }

            table();
```